# Como elimar un valor de un array por su id con JavaScript

Tags: javascript, array

Como puedo encontrar un valor por su id y elminarlo retornando un nuevo array sin este
he estado probando con esto

```
const crashCart = (id) => {

        const cartItem = cartItems.find((item) => item.id != id);
        if (cartItem) {
                // setCartItems([...cartItem]),
                console.log("cartItem",cartItem);
                        
        } else {
            setCartItems([...cartItems]);
        }
    };
```

Al pasarle el id recivo el objeto que quiero quitar como puedo crear el nuevo array sin este objeto?

Comment: Cambia `find` por `filter` y listo

Comment: Muchas gracias! eso era todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si es un array puedes usar el método array.filter(), este método recorre el array y devuelve otro array con los elementos que cumplen la condición pasada mediante un callback

```
varlista=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
var elim=2; 
listanueva=lista.filter((v)=>{return v != elim}, elim)
```

Comment: Gracias!! ya pude hacerlo